# Adobe Audience Manager - Stitching visitors across devices

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

Me and my team is new to Adobe Audience Manager and we are trying to figure out ways to stitch visitors cookies across devices (of the same visitor) once user does authentication (for ex: logins).
Have setup Adobe Analytics as well and have done integration to send data from Adobe Analytics to Adobe Audience Manager.

Primarily, we are trying to build a unified visitor's journey which as you would know will have endless benefits once we have it.

Any pointers/information or relevant doc will help a lot. Just ensuring we are moving in the right direction.

Regards, 
Adwait

Answer (score 0):

You can stitch user devices together (after authentication) by configuring ID sync and profile merge rules.
Here are the steps that you could follow

1. Configure a Cross device datasource (for merging online & offline data)

   - Go to `Audience Data > Data Sources > Add New`
   - name the data source as `Cross Device ID Sync`
   - Enter the following Integration code `offlinesyncid`, which is your own, unique ID for this data source.
   - In the ID Type choose `Cross Device`
   - In the ID Definition choose `Person`
   - In the `Data Export Controls` tick the `No ristriction` checkbox and make sure all other checkboxes are unticked.
   - In the `Data Source Settings` tick the `Inbound` checkbox and make sure the `Customer ID` radio button is chosen
   - In the `Data Source Settings` tick the `Outbound` checkbox
   - Make sure the `Use as Authenticated Profile` checkbox is ticked
   - Tick the `Share associated visitor or device IDs across the Audience Manager platform` checkbox
   - Save the datasource
   - Note the ID of the datasource you just created as we will use it in the following steps. Let's assume it is 123456
2. Configure an Online ID Sync datasource

   - Go to `Audience Data > Data Sources > Add New`
   - name the data source as `Online ID Sync`
   - Enter the following Integration code `sitesyncid`
   - In the ID Type choose `Cookie`
   - In the `Data Export Controls` tick the `No ristriction` checkbox and make sure all other checkboxes are unticked.
   - In the `Data Source Settings` tick the `Inbound` checkbox and make sure the `Customer ID` radio button is chosen
   - In the `Data Source Settings` tick the `Outbound`, `Share Enabled`, and `Share associated visitor or device IDs across the Audience Manager platform` checkboxes.
   - Save the datasource
3. Profile Merge Rule Setup

   - Go to `Audience Data > Profile Merge Rules > Add New Rule`
   - Name the new rule as `Last Authenticated with Profile Link Device Graph`
   - in the `Profile Merge Rule Setup` section choose the `Last Authenticated Profiles` radio button and tick the `Cross Device ID Sync - Person` datasource
   - From the `Device Options` section, choose the `Profile Link Device Graph`
4. Build the ID Sync code on your website

   Assuming that you are using the dil.js code here is an example of how you can perform the ID sync

   ```
   var customerID = "<customer ID e.g. 56789142>"; //Replace the text between the double quotes with your own authenticated customer ID
   if (customerID) {
     var yoursiteDIL = DIL.create({
       partner : "<partner name>", //The partner name given to you by Adobe.
       uuidCookie : {
       name : "aam_uuid",
       days : 30
       },
       visitorService: {
       namespace: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeOrg" //insert adobe org id here.
       },
       containerNSID: '0', // Recommended to have this set to zero. However, it could change depending on how many completely separate sites you run.
       declaredId : {
       dpid : "123456" , //This is the ID of the Cross Device datasource that you just created
       dpuuid : customerID
       }
     });

     var c = decodeURIComponent('%01');
     var cidObject = {
       cid_ic : 'sitesyncid' + c + customerID + c + '1' //this is the integration code you set for the Online ID Sync datasource
     };

     yoursiteDIL.api.signals(cidObject, 'd_');
     yoursiteDIL.api.signals({c_sitesyncid: customerID});
   } else {
     var yoursiteDIL = DIL.create({
       partner : "<partner name>",
       uuidCookie : {
       name : "aam_uuid",
       days : 30
       },
       visitorService: {
       namespace: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@AdobeOrg" //insert adobe org id here.
       }
     });
   }

   yoursiteDIL.api.signals({    "signalKey": "signalValue"});
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can try setting up the Adobe Analytics s.visitorID based on the login details.

https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/visid_custom.html

Comment: You should NOT use the s.visitorID if you are using the Visitor ID Service or Audience Manager. This variable is very problematic, avoid using it.